# Can I force Google appengine to send subsequent http request from same outbound IP

Tags: google-app-engine

I know that normally in GAE "two sequential API calls from the same application may appear to originate from two different IP addresses".

However some services try to verify that an authentication request and the following request using the session credentials come from the same IP.

Is there any way to make subsequent calls use the same IP?